# Find the Jordan form for a 3x3 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

When doing a Jordan decomposition on a matrix whose geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue $\lambda$ is less than the algebraic multiplicity, I thought I could use the eigenvectors from the generalized eigenspace. But it does not work for the following matrix $A$:

$A =
\begin{bmatrix}
7 & -1 & 1 \\
8 & 1 & 2 \\
-6 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

This matrix has an eigenvalue 3 and an eigenvector $\begin{bmatrix} 0.33333333\\0.66666667\\-0.66666667\end{bmatrix}$.

$A-\lambda I = 
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & -1 & 1 \\
8 & -2 & 2 \\
-6 & 1 & -2
\end{bmatrix}$

$\ker((A-\lambda I)^1) = 
\begin{bmatrix} 0.33333333\\0.66666667\\-0.66666667\end{bmatrix}$.

$\ker((A-\lambda I)^2) = 
s.\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix} + 
t.\begin{bmatrix} 0.4472136\\0.89442719\\0\end{bmatrix} $

Putting those generalized Eigenspaces together, I got

$P_{bad} = \begin{bmatrix}
0.33333333 & 0 & 0.4472136 \\
0.66666667 & 0 & 0.89442719 \\
-0.66666667 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

But this $P_{bad}$ is singular. Also $(A-\lambda I)^3 = 0$. So I can't get any more generalized eigenvectors.

If I use a different method to create generalized Eigen vectors, it works.

$(A - \lambda I)p2 = p1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\2\\-2\end{bmatrix}$

$(A - \lambda I)p3 = p2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0.5\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$

$p3 = \begin{bmatrix} -0.5\\-2\\0.5\end{bmatrix}$

Then I got $P_{good}=[p1,p2,p3] = \begin{bmatrix}
1  & 0.5 & -0.5 \\
2  & 1   & -2 \\
-2 & 0   & 0.5
\end{bmatrix}$

This $P_{good}$ works and I got Jordan form as

$P^{-1}AP=\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$

Can anyone help me understand why the first method got me a bad $P$...?

Comment: Eigenvalues can't be vectors. After you say the eigenvalue is $3$, should the next one be "eigenvector"?

Comment: Note that the kernel of $A-\lambda I$ is *contained* in the kernel of $(A-\lambda I)^2$. So of course you cannot take a basis for the nulspace of $(A-\lambda I)^2$, and then *add* a basis for the nullspace of $(A-\lambda I)$, and hope to get a linearly independent set: the vector in the nullspace of $A-\lambda I$ is necessariily a linear combination of the vectors in the basis of $(A-\lambda I)^2$. So what you tried to do was doomed to fail. You can't do it that way.

Comment: Thank you Arturo. So do I have to take all the basis of the eigen space only from the nulspace of $(A-\lambda I)^2$ ?

Comment: That will not suffice, since it will only give you two generalized eigenvectors, one of which will be in $N(A-\lambda I)$, and the other will be in $N(A-\lambda I)^2-N(A-\lambda I)$. You need to construct the cycles in the correct way, which in this case means finding an element of $N(A-\lambda I)^3-N(A-\lambda I)$, and using it to generate the cycle of generalized eigenvectors.

Comment: thank you again... $(A-\lambda I)^3$ is $0$. So $N(A-\lambda I)^3$ is the entire $\mathbb{R}^3$. So $N(A-\lambda I)^3 - N(A-\lambda I)$ is the compliment space of $N(A-\lambda I)$. I picked up $\begin{bmatrix} -0.66666667\\0.66666667\\0.33333333\end{bmatrix}$ but was not able to get a good P...

Comment: What you need is something that is not in $N(A-\lambda I)^2$, not merely not in $N(A-\lambda I)$. At this point, I'll just say this: you are too confused. Review the material on the Jordan form and learn the method.

Comment: Thank you Arturo again. So I need to pick up one generalized eigen vector from each $N(A-\lambda I)^k$ in the ascending order (from 1 to k) and put them in the P in the same order to create Jordan form... I can't pick up all the generalized vectors from $N(A-\lambda I)^k$ ... I thought the generalized eigenspace is $N(A-\lambda I)^k$. but it is actually $N(A-\lambda I)^1 + N(A-\lambda I)^2 + ... + N(A-\lambda I)^k$ .... is it correct?

Comment: No, that is incorect. I'm not going to keep writing comments; this thread is too long already. You need to review this material, because you are confused.

Comment: Thank you again Arturo. I think I understand this now. So in this case, the generalized eigen vectors are a basis of $N(A-\lambda I)^3 = \mathbb{R}^3$. But I need to find a the first basis vector e, where $(A-\lambda I)^2 e \ne \vec{0}$. If I found such vector, ($(A-\lambda I)^2 e, (A-\lambda I) e, e$) is P. I misunderstood that any three linearly independent vectors of $\mathbb{R}^3$ could be generalized eigen vectors.